# how to control recursion in cpp

Tags: c++, recursion

Hi I am building a project using cpp in that I am heavily using recursion but I am not able to get

```
void user1() {
       avg=average(totall, dice);
        if(avg>=3){
            totallSum+=totall;
            // cout<<name1<<" is safe! "<<name1<<"'s turn is score now "<<totallSum<<endl;
            if(totallSum<point){
                cout<<name1<<" is safe! "<<name1<<"'s turn is score now "<<totallSum<<endl;
            }
            else { 
                user1totall+=totallSum;
                break;
            }
        }
        else{

            totallSum=0;
            user2(name1, name2,point,5,0,user1totall,user2totall,++turn2);
        }
        user2(name1, name2,point,dice,totallSum,user1totall,user2totall,++turn2);
}
```

this is the small snippet of the code I wrote
here the issue is that in the else block where the `user2` function is being called it works completely fine but when it is executed completely it don't exit this `user1` function instead it agains call the `user2` function on the second last line
can anyone please tell how to resolve this issue

Comment: `break` cannot be used outside of `switch` or loop(`for`/`while`)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the memory is stored in stack (Last in First out).
When its calling `user2` function first time then the program will complete its execution first due to Stack memory
after it has executed `user2` function then it will continue again back to `user1` and move next where it is again calling `user2`.

To resolve this error change `user1` return type from `void` to `int`
and when you are calling `user2` function
after that line add
`return 0;`
it will work completely fine

Comment: you don't have to change it to int. You can return from a void function by writing `return;`

Comment: ook thanks I did't knew this